# How to retrieve the value of a key(nested) in JSON which is stored in mongoDB using JAVA?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

Below is the JSON file from which I want to retrieve the phone number:

```
"_data" : {
        "Variable key" : {

        "Name" : "Hello World",
        "Phone" : "Phone : 123-456-6789 ",
        "Region" : "New York",
        "Description" : ""
         }
    }
```

My Java Code is:

```
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
            field.put("_data.Phone", 1);
            DBCursor cursor = table.find(query,field);
            String str;
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
                str=cursor.curr().get("_data.Phone").toString();
                System.out.println(str);
                }
```

which will return null as I'm not considering the variable key.

My problem is there are many JSON files present in the mongo database each having different "Variable Key" and this key may change after sometime. As this key may change over time, how can I retrieve the phone number ?

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

Which phone numbers do you want? Your query will return all documents and you are trying to project out just the phone number, but with an incorrect projection specification. If you want all phone numbers, just leave out the projection specification entirely or project on `{ "_data" : 1 }`. If you want the phone numbers associated with specific variable keys, project those out using dot notation like `{ "_data.key_name.Phone" : 1 }`. If you don't know the names of the keys that you want to project on, then that is your root problem that you need to solve before you ask MongoDB to return something that you don't know that you want (or that you don't want).